# Publish content with URL from Token

Tags: 7, uri, emails, tokens, nodes

I'm building a website where you're supposed to add content, which will be unpublished until you click a link in the email you got after adding the content.

So, is there a way to get the publish URL from the content you just added with Token? Or is't possible to get the publish URL whatsoever?

Also, it is an anonymous user that is supposed to click the publishing URL.

Thanks in advance.